# Why would an iptables rule for ANY proto only allow ICMP traffic?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, routing, gateway

Basically, I have a Linux box (Ubuntu Focal) configured as a gateway:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1   #Enable ipv4 forwarding
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens160 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE  #NAT 192.168.1.x to internet behind interface ens160
```

Having done this, I can ping successfully:
[image: successful pings]

And I see the hit count increase on the masquerade rule (from 1 to 2 in this example):
[image: hit count increase]

The rule is duplicated in the previous picture because of all the stuff I was trying at the time I took the screenshot, but its not really significant in this example I don't think.

So I can ping 8.8.8.8 just fine, but if I try to do something else, like for example a DNS lookup like

```
dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com
```

This fails and the hit count on the rule does not increase.

I also tried using telnet to open an HTTP (not HTTPS) website by IP address (not name), and this also fails, with the hit count not increasing.

I'm really at a loss for what could be causing this, since this procedure normally works and the rule itself is saying that it applies to all protocols, not just ICMP, but it seems to be the case that I can ping anything by IP address, but DNS lookups (UDP) and TCP connections are failing because the gateway is not sending them out.

I did a tcpdump as well and you can see the packets coming in as 192.168.1.x, and in the case of ICMP you also see the NATted packets leaving, but for UDP/TCP you don't see anything leaving.

What might be the issue here?

---

Edit: Adding some more info as per some of the feedback from comments

The `filter` and `raw` tables don't seem to have anything in there. I'm not sure if I'm using the right command to check these, but I think so:
[image: filter & raw tables]

`iptables-save -c` doesn't show anything besides what I expect either. (There are some dupes of the rule I added due to repeated trial & error, but I don't think these have any impact):

```
sudo iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Tue May  2 18:59:25 2023
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [290378:642993821]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [26621:1727859]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May  2 18:59:25 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Tue May  2 18:59:25 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [290051:642964315]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [140:11615]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [26631:1728900]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May  2 18:59:25 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Tue May  2 18:59:25 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [72935:11925313]
:INPUT ACCEPT [72704:11903229]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1643:146886]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1643:146886]
[11:924] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/32 -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May  2 18:59:25 2023
```

I myself am not really able to get any additional insights from this output, any suggestions?

---

Edit 2: Adding some more info as per the comments

I don't believe NFtables was ever installed, but `nft list chains` doesn't give anything, and the routes for icmp and udp seem to be the same:
[image: NFtables chains & routes]

It's really quite strange since DNS requests originating from within the gateway VM itself (the system DNS isn't set to 8.8.8.8) seem to get SNATted and go out no problem, and even get a response, but for whatever reason inbound DNS requests from the private LAN just die on arrival:
[image: tcpdump]

Comment: double-check that you don't have anything messing it up in the (default) `filter` table, or in the `raw` table.

Comment: And if you want us to verify, add in the question the output of `iptables-save -c` (as text, not as screenshot please), which will include all tables (not just nat) and also hit counts.

Comment: I updated the original question, but just from looking at those outputs I don't see anything glaring. @ilkkachu as well

Comment: What are the outputs of `nft list chains`, `ip route get 8.8.8.8 ipproto icmp` and `ip route get 8.8.8.8 ipproto udp dport 53`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging looked pretty normal to me, updated the original question.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem could be. So all I have left is to uggest the tool for desperate siturations: trace the packets in Netfilter (search for `TRACE` in `man iptables-extensions`): `iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p icmp -d 1.2.3.4 -j TRACE` You should have two such rules, one for a packet which does go out and one for a packet which does not. Make those rules precise so that they match only your test packets or you will get flooded in log output. The system log will tell you which rule/policy killed your packet.